# Roots of $det(A+pB)=0$ with $A$ and $B$ two real diagonally dominant symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two real matrices $A$ and $B$ that are symmetric and weakly diagonal dominant. Diagonal elements of $A$ and $B$ are positive and off-diagonal elements are negative.

I would like to prove that in general, the values ​​of $p$ for which $det(A+pB)=0$ are real and negative. I would also like to know in which case we have a zero root $p=0$.

Thanks in advance for any help and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: The Gershgorin circle theorem can be used to provide some estimates if you know the components of $A$ and $B$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem

Comment: Your hypothesis is not quite right... for simple counter-examples to your hypothesis, let $A,B$ both be graph Laplacians. What is true is $\det\big(A + pB\big)$ is either the zero polynomial (hence all values in $\mathbb C$ are roots) or else it is a polynomial with only real roots; I proved this here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4728536/simultaneous-diagonalization-of-a-positive-semi-definite-matrix-and-a-symmetric/ .  If $\ker A \cap  \ker B = \big\{\mathbf 0 \big\}$ then you can argue $p\gt 0$ means $A+pB \succ \mathbf 0$ giving your result.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer seems very useful to me. I will look in more detail why the situation of a determinant reduced to 0 does not occur in my problem.

Comment: @user8675309, I thought I understood that you indicate that with two Laplacian matrices the determinant should be identically zero. I tried with Laplacian matrices of two graphs which have 4 vertices and this is not the case. Can you elaborate a little? (I know very little about graph theory and I see that I forgot to put your name in my previous answer)

Comment: the ones vector is in the kernel of a graph laplacian so $(A+pB)\mathbf 1 = A\mathbf 1 + pB\mathbf 1 =\mathbf 0 + \mathbf 0 = \mathbf 0$ i.e. $(A+pB)$ is singular for all $p$. Compare with my link.

Comment: @user8675309, Thanks a lot. I work on electrical networks and two vertices can be connected by more than one edge (components in parallel). And so the Laplacian matrices that I had chosen were not suitable. I just saw that these are not "simple graphs". I still have a lot to understand on the subject.